# right set for range function angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```js
var app=angular.module('MyApp', []);

app.controller("MyControler", function($scope, $http, $filter) {
      $http.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/cars/?format=json").
        success(function(data) {
              $scope.list = data;
          });
    $scope.currentPage = 0;
    $scope.pageSize = 5;


    $scope.range = function() {
    var rangeSize = 10;
    var ret = [];
    var start;

    start = $scope.currentPage;
    if ( start > $scope.numberOfPages()-rangeSize ) {
      start = $scope.numberOfPages()-rangeSize+1;
    }

    for (var i=start; i<start+rangeSize; i++) {
      ret.push(i);
    }
    return ret;
  };

    $scope.numberOfPages=function(){
        var myFilteredData = $filter('filter')($scope.list, $scope.search);
        return Math.ceil(myFilteredData.length/$scope.pageSize);
    };

      $scope.prevPage = function() {
    if ($scope.currentPage > 0) {
      $scope.currentPage--;
    }
  };

  $scope.prevPageDisabled = function() {
    return $scope.currentPage === 0 ? "disabled" : "";
  };

    $scope.nextPage = function() {
    if ($scope.currentPage < $scope.numberOfPages()) {
      $scope.currentPage++;
    }
  };

  $scope.nextPageDisabled = function() {
    return $scope.currentPage === $scope.numberOfPages() ? "disabled" : "";
  };
 $scope.setPage = function(n) {
    $scope.currentPage = n;
  };
});
```

```html
        <div class="pagination">
            <ul>
              <li ng-class="prevPageDisabled()">
                <a href ng-click="prevPage()">« Prev</a>
              </li>
              <li ng-repeat="n in range()"
              ng-class="{active: n == currentPage}" ng-click="setPage(n)">
              <a href="#">{{n+1}}</a>
            </li>
              <li ng-class="nextPageDisabled()">
                <a href ng-click="nextPage()">Next »</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>

  </div>







</body>

 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
 
</html>
```

So i tried to reduce my code, my range function set visibility of pagination, how many pages, but when i start filtering and results are very thin like just few objects left, pagination show me as well pages with minus.

I thought it is because it show me how many pages are left behind or not included when i filter?

Comment: Can you remove all the unnecessary code and keep only a minimal reproducible example? Must we weed through the entire code to help?

Comment: we don't know your app ... what does setting range even mean? We shouldn't have to wade through everything to try to guess what behavior is expected

Comment: I changed my code, sorry guys, I am still newbaby with almost everything here ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
  $scope.range = function() {
    var rangeSize = 5;
    var ret = [];
    var start;

    start = $scope.currentPage;
    if ( start > $scope.numberOfPages()-rangeSize ) {
      start = $scope.numberOfPages()-rangeSize;
        if (start < 0) {
            start = 0;
        }
    }

    for (var i=start; i<start+rangeSize && i < $scope.numberOfPages(); i++) {
      ret.push(i);
    }
    return ret;
  };
```

Okey i found solution ;)